# Scroll not working even though I have overflow: scroll set

Tags: html, scroll

There are scads of questions on this, but after 2 hours of looking, I haven't found an answer:

I have a div that has a canvas inside it. (Although I've also tried with just ordinary text).

```
<div class="gpdialog" style="width: 90%; display: block; position: fixed; left: 23.25px; top: 41.95px;">   
    <div id="colorSchemeEditor" ;="" style="overflow :scroll">
        <h1 class="centered">   
            Color Scheme Picker   
        </h1>
        <div class="widget_container">
            <canvas id="color_picker_canvas" ;="" height="600" width="500"></canvas>
            <div class="yui3-g">
                <div class="yui3-u-1-1"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

I draw on the canvas, and the drawing extends down below the page.  The scrollbar shows up on the right hand side, but isn't activated.  This happens in both Chrome and Firefox.  (Haven't tried any other browsers.)  There is no access to the bottom of the page (where there are buttons).  I'm not sure what else to look for.

TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple factors here, and I haven't tested all cases but:

(1)  The 'overflow: scroll' probably should be in the immediately enclosing div

(2) The div with the scroll needs to have height and width specifiers.

(3) The height and width specifiers need to be IN THE SAME STYLE ELEMENT with the overflow specifier.

Thus:

```
    <div style="height: 300px; width:300px; overflow :scroll;">
```

But NOT

```
    <div height="300px"; width="300px"; style="overflow: scroll;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong.

```
<div id="colorSchemeEditor" ;="" style="overflow :scroll">
```

Should be..

```
<div id="colorSchemeEditor" ;="" style="overflow :scroll;">
```

You forgot the semi-colon. But what's up with `;=""`?

Comment: Moving the semicolon doesn't fix it.  (But thanks for the try).  the ;="" I'm not sure where it comes from.  It's not in my html, but it gets run through a template parser that may insert it.  When I remove that in the Firefox debugger, it doesn't fix the problem either.

Comment: What does the debugger show for the overflow :scroll; property?